# Schedule task doesn't run

Tags: powershell

The whole script.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "$getservice = Get-Service -Name wuauserv; If($getservice.Status -eq 'Running') {Start-Sleep -s 10; Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat} Else {Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat}"
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At 9am -DaysOfWeek Thursday -WeeksInterval 4
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8 -StartWhenAvailable
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID System -RunLevel Highest
$params = @{
"TaskName"  = "Office"
"Action"    = $action
"Trigger"   = $trigger
"Settings"  = $settings
"Principal" = $principal
}
Register-ScheduledTask @Params -Force
```

1.bat consists of one line "notepad" for example. But when I launch task nothing happens. Withal script imported whithout any errors.
So the question is where did I make mistake in

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "$getservice = Get-Service -Name wuauserv; If($getservice.Status -eq 'Running') {Start-Sleep -s 10; Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat} Else {Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat}"
```

This code runs proprely!

```
$getservice = Get-Service -Name wuauserv; If($getservice.Status -eq 'Running') {Start-Sleep -s 10; Start-Process -FilePath D:\Программы\Прочее\1.bat} Else {Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your code to run with success when I changed your first line to this:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "`$getservice = Get-Service -Name wuauserv; If(`$getservice.Status -eq 'Running') {Start-Sleep -s 10; Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat} Else {Start-Process -FilePath D:\1.bat}"
```

Note the backticks that precede the dollar signs in the code.  You have to escape dollar-signs or the PowerShell treats them as variables and interpolates them, which munges up the PowerShell command you want to send to your task.

I could not test 1.bat with "notepad" since I would not see it logged on as me, so I used this for 1.bat:

```
rem notepad.exe
echo Test123 >> D:\1.txt
```